# Java: Read a File & Split a line into separate string

Tags: java, string, split

I want to read a file, file.txt that contains word pairs like this...

```
yaniv:bobo
```

After reading this file.txt , I want to split this text and put  each words in variables and try to compare them like this :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
           
           String descritpion = scan.nextLine();
           
           System.out.println("line" +descritpion);  
          
           String []temp = descritpion.split(":");   
          
           String name = temp[0];   
           String surname = temp[1];
      
          System.out.println("name : "+ name);   
          System.out.println("surname : "+ surname);
      
             
 }
```

```
if(surname == "bobo") {
                System.out.println("date set from file ");
                GUI_view.getDateChooser().setDate( new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(part1) );
                }
```

BUT I GET THIS ERROR ?? WHY ?? WHats Wrong ??

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at controller.TaskController.openFile(TaskController.java:213)
    at controller.TaskController.lambda$11(TaskController.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well, the Exception seems to originate on `TaskController.openFile()`. So you might need to show us that.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly where the problem lies, since we don't know if this is the openFile() function you're showing us. Please include this in the question if this is the case. Assuming the code you've shown us is the source of error, I can see this problem arise if the file provided has an entry without the ':' separator, which would result in an array with 1 element instead of 2; throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for index 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how your file ends. `Scanner` is clever enough to throw away a single line-break from the end. However if there is anything (like a space or another line break) afterwards, that's going to be a new line to be read.
In such cases

> ```
> String descritpion = scan.nextLine();
> ```

will read an empty-ish string, then

> ```
> String []temp = descritpion.split(":");
> ```

splits it into a single-item array, where

> ```
> String name = temp[0];
> ```

contains the entire string (being empty or containing a single space or something), that's how it passes
but

> ```
> String surname = temp[1];
> ```

does not exist, and that's why it throws an exception.
However in such cases a `line` should appear on screen prior to the exception. See test (with strings instead of files) here: https://ideone.com/ixo0kd - the no-line-break, and single-line-break cases work fine, the space-after-line-break and double-line-break cases throw the exception, but have an empty `line` displayed before.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will fix your problem, but instead of

```
if(surname == "bobo") {
```

Use:

```
if(surname.contains("bobo")) {
```

surname == "bobo" will return false as its comparing the address of surname

Comment: thanks you for your answer , but it still doesn't  work with "contain()" , i don't understand why it is throwing me this exception